# TCP response cut short

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking, tcp

I'm using the TCP client in WP7. At the moment i'm just using the example code from MSDN, so it should work. But for some reason this particular response is being cut short.

It should reply (followed by a lot of null bytes, from the buffer):

> 202- multiline response follows\r\ntimestamp=0x00000000 checksum=0x00000000\r\nname=\"FLASH:Flash\xshell.xex\"\r\n.\r\n

But instead it's returning (and doesn't have any trailing null bytes):

> 202- multiline response follows\r\n

My code for getting the response from the TCP server is:

```
        try
        {
            if (!_isConnected)
                Connect();
            if (!_isConnected)
                return null;

            SendTextCommand(command);

            string response = "";

            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = _socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            socketEventArg.UserToken = null;

            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {
                    response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Buffer);
                    response = response.Trim('\0');
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception(e.SocketError.ToString());

                _pausingThread.Set();
            });

            _pausingThread.Reset();
            _socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);
            _pausingThread.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { GenerateException(ex.Message); return "123"; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I presume that sometimes the buffer doesn't hold all the data before you read it. Try with Thread.Sleep(100); or something that waits a little bit ans see if it will have the full string. Also, how much is MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, is it enough?

Comment: Yeah, If I call the function again, it returns a bit more of the output string. And MAX_BUFFER_SIZE is (3 * 1024), so it is big enough. And where would you suggest putting the Thread.Sleep?

Comment: put it after this line if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) before you read the Buffer, I know it is a lousy solution but you can't control the speed of the network and other layers of the protocol stack. This is happening all the time so you will have to adapt your program logic for this case (i.e adding some special character(s) at the end of the string, hence implementing your own protocol on top of the TCP/IP protocol).

Comment: Have you tried it?Does it work?

Comment: A friend of mine told me to loop until the entire message had been delivered. As a TCP connection isn't like a stream. I'll post the working code above.

Comment: The ideal way to fix it, is to add a length byte and receive data until the size is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, you have to check if the response is multi-line. If it is, then you loop until it finishes with ".\r\n". Otherwise you read once and you've finished. Like so:

```
public string GetFromTextCommand(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_isConnected)
                Connect();
            if (!_isConnected)
                return null;

            SendTextCommand(command);

            string response = GetFromTextCommand();

            if (response.StartsWith("202"))
            {
                while (!response.EndsWith(".\r\n"))
                {
                    string newResponse = GetFromTextCommand();

                    response += newResponse;
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { GenerateException(ex.Message); return null; }
    }
    public string GetFromTextCommand()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_isConnected)
                Connect();
            if (!_isConnected)
                return null;

            string response = "";

            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = _socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            socketEventArg.UserToken = null;

            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {
                    response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Buffer);
                    response = response.Trim('\0');
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception(e.SocketError.ToString());

                _pausingThread.Set();
            });

            _pausingThread.Reset();
            _socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);
            _pausingThread.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { GenerateException(ex.Message); return null; }
    }
```